# Can double dipping be reasonable?

Tags: time-series, bayesian, econometrics, markov-chain-montecarlo

I found a [paper](https://7564fa1b-a-62cb3a1a-s-sites.googlegroups.com/site/regisbarnichon/cv/FAIR.pdf?attachauth=ANoY7cotK0pHXV29ofeaWl9nW04h3OYYAMuzhIcH3HN6rGHw0fz8h3b_vTQXu44UcW0UqC_tDyGtu_9T-KhiQ2suWXbH1rpZeTh0NnjXHz8gAfc7i53y2R5ntQJEw351tf5jBdaH6C6slGrpSD17XupEGtzl3glGxanETKBdeBcV9x5tQU-EyfWFJX1Ovy35ZMenQC6St9JHOkImECmLLcpUTO_wY7cD2Q%3D%3D&attredirects=0) where the authors used bayesian methods to estimate asymmetric effects in impulse response functions. In short the estimation procedure is:

1. Calculate a VAR and Impulse responses (no matter what identification strategy).
2. Express this IRF´s as a a set of gaussian basis function. (This reduces the number of parameter)
3. Use this estimates as the initial guess (=prior?) of a Metropolis-Hastings Algorithm.

All steps use the same data.

I'm a bit confused if it makes sense to extract the prior information from the same data where the MCMC algorithm will be used in the next step? I learned that "double dipping" is a problem in bayesian statistics. Since it is a relatively well-known paper, I assume that there is an explanation for this point, but I don't get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the overall pattern you describe: yes this could be reasonable (or, it's not obviously unreasonable).

Why? The starting position for MCMC can be arbitrarily chosen. So long as the chain is run to stationarity. Choosing a reasonable starting position will reduce compute time.

You do have to look out for some problems though. In the case of a multimodal distribution, starting multiple chains at the same mode could fool you into believing you've sampled the whole space when you have not (but this is a special problem).

Using the data to form a prior is a conceptually separate issue, which sometimes goes under the name of empirical Bayes. Empirical Bayes is neither wrong nor right.

In my *opinion* it's often safe to extract some extremely general information from a dataset using empirical  Bayes. E.g. extract the range of possible values |max - min| of the data in order to calibrate, say, a prior on the variance of some parameter - is it 10^1 or 10^6? But not, e.g. what was the value of unit $i$ at time $t$?

Comment: Thank you very much. You gave me exactly the buzzwords I needed to know :) (sorry for the late acceptance -> I did some readings first)